# Express 4 + Passport, req.user is undefined - function calling order?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I encountered a very peculiar problem. I was trying to get express + passport to work. As vast majority of the examples online were for express 3, the process took me sometime - eventually I got the Google authentication to work. I was trying to bind the Google account to a local account, which requires searching for an account from Mongo DB. The following are the part of code that works:

```
//Serialize function
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

//Deserialize function
passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
});

//Strategy
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        returnURL: 'http://localhost:8000/auth/google/return',
        realm: 'http://localhost:8000/'
    },
    function(identifier, profile, done) {

        process.nextTick(function() {

            profile.identifier = identifier;

            return done(null, profile);
        });

    }
));
```

The following codes were verified to work. Everything works like a charm.
However, when I modified the code as follows:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
     done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {

     //note that only change is to find user from database, User is a mongoose instance
     //very straightforward, verified user can be found.
     User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        done(err, user);
     });
});
```

And the strategy was changed to create a user if not found:

```
        process.nextTick(function() {

             profile.id = identifier;

             User.findOne({
                 'google.id': profile.id
             }, function(err, user) {
                 if (err) {
                     return done(err); // don't even know what done means!
                 } else if (user) {
                     return done(null, user);
                 } else {
                     //very easy to create and save to database.
                     //create a new user instance
                     var newUser = new User();

                     newUser.google.id = profile.id;
                     newUser.google.name = profile.displayName;
                     newUser.google.email = profile.emails[0].value;

                     newUser.local.email = newUser.google.email;
                     newUser.local.name = newUser.google.name;
                     // newUser.id = newUser._id;

                     //it should have been saved to database?
                     newUser.save(function(err) {
                         if (err)
                             throw err;

                         //The done is called once is saved.
                         return done(null, newUser);
                     });
                 }
             });
         });
```

And this is the router, which was placed after all the necessary initialization for passport.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Rendering...");
    console.log(req.user);

    res.render('index', {
        user: req.user
    });

    console.log("Rendering done...");
});
```

Now here's the funny part:
When I access the `URL`, the console.log within the `app.get('/')` was called AFTER the page was loaded, and `req.user` is NOT undefined. When it was working, the console.log was called in the correct order. It seems that when page was rendered, the `req.user` was not yet initialized - but I just can't figure out why the console.log functions were called AFTER res.render - it doesn't make any sense to me. It could be a result of some async logic...

Anyone has any ideas? Thank you. I will update the code to `Github`.

I also tried `websocket` to access `req.handshake.use`r - all the data is there. It's somehow just when `res.render` was called, it was not initialized yet.

Comment: Short: You can't. long: You can't b/c passport hasn't been updated for express 4, which is really recent. I tried to update express and failed, then I gave up otherwise I would have wasted my time.

Comment: I have been using Passport successfully with Express 4.

Comment: I tried to run on Ubuntu Amazon. Same issue.
console.log(req.user); is printed in the console AFTER res.render; and when it's printed out, apparently the req.user is NOT undefined. I feel some async logic has messed up the whole thing...

Comment: Same issue. Further, I do not have the additional complications of trying to add in Mongo. In my case, I'm using the Express 4 examples provided by [maxdow](https://github.com/maxdow/passport-local). I was able to get his Express 4 example to work perfectly with a only a few deprecation errors that we have addressed. All that was going fine, but I decided to drop the EJS usage and switch the example over to Jade and this is when I started encountering the res.user not initialized problem.

Comment: In my case, I was able to correct this problem. Seems that res.user is (perhaps obviously) undefined until a user successfully logs in. And, Jade did not like trying to use an undefined value. Fixed it in my case by changing: `res.render('index', { user: req.user });` to `res.render('index', { user: (typeof(req.user)=='undefined'?false:req.user });`